# Return values of an array from behind (last element) php

Tags: php, arrays

say I have an array

```
$test_backwards=array("something1","something2","something3");
```

this is just a testing example and it's important to note that values will be added dinamically in my final array. so is it possible to dynamically return values from behind, namely starting from the last element?

something like this but backwards

```
for($i=0;$i<count($test_backwards);$i++) {
echo $test_backwards.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just start at the end and decrement your index:*

```
for ($i = count($test_backwards) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo $test_backwards[$i].'<br>';
}
```

*or use [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/array_reverse) (slower):*

```
$test_backwards = array_reverse($test_backwards);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($test_backwards); $i++) {
    echo $test_backwards[$i].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [array_pop()](http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.array-pop.php), if you do not need to keep this array. Or you can assign it to a temp array and then array_pop it, it will get and delete value from last.

```
$temp = $test_backwards;
while(($item = array_pop($temp)) !== NULL ) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: code example would be: `while (!is_null($var = array_pop($test_backwards))) { echo "$var<br>"; }`